# StackOverflowError when trying to call a method which calls another method from another class

Tags: java

I think the method is calling itself or something.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom)
    {
        boolean raak = isRaak(rij, kolom); //this "isRaak" should refer to a method in another class, not sure how to do this...
        return raak;
    }
```

Comment: `boolean raak = new AnotherClass().isRaak(rij, kolom);`

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

If that is a instance method, You need to create `instance` of that and call it.

```
public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom)
    {
        AnotherClass an =new AnotherClass();
        boolean raak = an.isRaak(rij, kolom);  
        return raak;
    }
```

If that is a static method

```
public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom)
    {            
        boolean raak = AnotherClass.isRaak(rij, kolom);   
        return raak;
    }
```

But your method seems like an `Utility` method to me,So go for static method,if so.

Before proceeding further, Prefer to read:

- [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty evident. Call the method by prefixing the classname if the method is static, else call the method with the object of the class.

Comment: Could you provide an example on your second suggestion please?

Comment: Please refer to answer posted by Suresh Atta

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways to accomplish this:

1. Create a new instance of your `AnotherClass` and call the `isRaak` method:

   ```
   public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom) {
       return new Anotherclass().isRaak(rij, kolom);
   }
   ```
2. Reuse a current instance of your `AnotherClass` and call the `isRaak` method:

   ```
   //field in the class initialized somewhere along your current class...
   AnotherClass anotherClass = ...
   public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom) {
       return anotherClass.isRaak(rij, kolom);
   }
   ```
3. If the method is declared as `static` in `AnotherClass`, call the method directly from the class without using an instance.

   ```
   public boolean isRaak(int rij, int kolom) {
       return AnotherClass.isRaak(rij, kolom);
   }
   ```

Note that the first two methods assume the constructor of `AnotherClass` doesn't need to receive parameters, but this should be adaptable to your specific case.